# Fetching API from Module Export File with Promises React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, es6-promise, module.exports

I want to fetch an API, exported from module file data.js

I am getting this error "err SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

The file below contains the API module

```
 /**
 * @typedef {object} PropertyType
 * @property {string} label - The text to display
 * @property {string} value - The enum value assigned
 */

 /**
 * Retrieve a list of all available property types.
 *
 * @returns {Promise<{ propertyTypes: PropertyType[] }>}
 */

async function getAvailablePropertyTypes() {
  await wait(randomInteger(500));

  return {
    propertyTypes: [
      { label: 'Semi-detached', value: 'semi-detached' },
      { label: 'Detached house', value: 'detached' },
      { label: 'Terraced house', value: 'terraced' },
      { label: 'Flat', value: 'flat' },
    ]
  };
}

export {getAvailablePropertyTypes};
```

The file below contains the imported API app.js

I think I am not fetching correctly at this line
const response = await fetch(getAvailablePropertyTypes.propertyTypes)

How do I fetch from this function getAvailablePropertyTypes.propertyTypes ??

```
import  {getAvailablePropertyTypes} from './properties'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {

useEffect( async () => {
      const response = await fetch(getAvailablePropertyTypes.propertyTypes)
      const data = await response.json()
      .then(res => {
        console.log('res', res)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err)
      })
    }, [])
    
    return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getAvailablePropertyTypes` is a function. It doesn't have a `propertyTypes` property, so you are going to get `undefined` for that.

`undefined` is not a URL to anything useful, so you get an error page when you make a network request to it. The error page is not JSON, hence the error message.

There's no URL anywhere near this code. It doesn't make sense to involve `fetch` at all.

`fetch` is useful for getting data from APIs that are implemented as web services. It won't help you with other kinds of APIs, including this one which is just some functions dealing with internal data.

So let's go back to the start and look at what you do have.

---

`getAvailablePropertyTypes` is a function. So call it.

```
const ret_value = getAvailablePropertyTypes();
```

It is `async` so it returns a promise, so await it.

```
const data = await ret_value;
```

The resolved value of the promise is an object which **does** have a `propertyTypes` value. So extract that.

```
const { propertyTypes } = data;
```

Now that is an array which you can do whatever you like with

```
console.log(propertyTypes);
```

Comment: Great thank you. I am getting this error from your answer "Unexpected reserved word 'await'"
on this line const data = await ret_value;

Comment: @LondonCreative — Works for me. Maybe you removed your code from your async useEffect callback. `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions.

Comment: Yes it worked now. Do I need to use .then .catch because it is a promise isn't it?

Comment: If you're using `await` then it is typical to use `try/catch` and not the promise `catch` method.